# XStream performance query

Tags: jakarta-ee, xstream

I am trying to get the xml conversion response for an object in my code as below

```
XStream xstream=new XStream();
```

`xstream.processAnnotations(`

```
new Class[]{SomeResponseBean.class,SomeSectionResponseBean.class});
xstream.toXML(objectForConversion);
```

Do we need to instantiate XStream instance for every conversion or we can have it a single instance and reuse ?

Our application has huge volume requests .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate XStream for every conversions since the XStream object is [Thread safe](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Scalability_Thread_safety). 
The initial instantiation/configuration of XStream is time-consuming, so it is a good thing to define the instance as static in your class :

```
   private static final XStream XSTREAM;
   static {
        XSTREAM = new XStream();
        XSTREAM.aliasPackage(...);
        //Other configurations
    }
```